# What is the advantage of using a timeout with a backoff policy?

Tags: networking, grpc

I don't understand the use of having a timeout with a back off policy. I was told that there is use to it, but I don't understand it.

A timeout, in this case, will allow a service to try and establish a connection for some time, then give up. The BackOff policy (exponential back off) will try to establish a connection, and if it fails, will wait some time, then try again and if it fails, wait the same amount of time or longer.

If BackOff policy will start a connection after the time out, then what use is the time out? If one service uses *only* Back Off, I cannot foresee a difference between it and another service that uses Back Off and a Timeout. Can someone explain the merit?

Thank you

Comment: The timeout is needed regardless; you are not going to wait forever for a response to come back. You would need to tweak the retries accordingly giving them a threshold (timeout + backoff strategy + some other factors...if any) because sometimes it makes sense to retry right away (a couple of times), but keep doing doing it continuously is non-sense, hence the backoff policy/strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backoff policy and default timeout are two completely separate options that do not interact.

In the semantics of gRPC, you establish a single connection to a server, and then make multiple independent requests on that one connection. The default timeout indicates how long a client should let any single request run before reporting that it has failed. The backoff policy, on the other hand, indicates how the client should reestablish that single connection if it is lost.

Comment: I am sure I am just misunderstanding something. Assume I have a service that has a timeout of 20 seconds and a back off policy (let us say it just retries a connection after five seconds). Assume also that the connection can only succeed after 60 seconds. In those first 20 seconds, what happens to the way that the service tries to establish a connection that is _different_ from the last 40 seconds? How does the time out affect the first 20 seconds?

Comment: I rewrote my answer to try to explain the separation more clearly. Does that help?

Comment: Oh! I get it. So, essentially, there are _multiple_ definitions of what a "fail" means. That makes total sense. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

A failure in a network with many services can trigger many retries. Exponential backoff reduces the network load while services are being restored and helps to prevent the retries themselves becoming part of the problem.

Adding randomness to the backoff timer also helps with retries that might impact one another. This is used, for example, on a shared media network like Ethernet to reduce the chance of a repeated collision when two nodes have detected a collision and are retransmitting.

Comment: I understand the merit behind using exponential back off. I don't understand the merit of using a time out *when* one is already using back off. What value does the time out add?